# MATCH AGAINST sql with keyword 'with'

Tags: sql, mariadb

Within my database I store some keywords in a separate column to match against with my query. For example by families: last name of both parents, their email and phone number. Then, I use the following query to retrieve data:

```
select * 
from `family` 
where MATCH(family.search_keywords) AGAINST ('their_very_nice_last_name')
```

It's all and good for most of the last names, however, one of the last names of the parents is "with". When I query their last name, I get no result. Is this a reserved word or something?

Comment: I can confirm `WITH` it is a reserved word on `MySQL` :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html  , `ORACLE` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm, SQL Server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: But also when i use it in quotes?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: I use the MariaDB

Comment: Then try and use backticks not quotes  `

Comment: So: MATCH(family.search_keywords) AGAINST (`with`) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239570/discussion-between-rick-van-der-heide-and-ergest-basha).

Comment: @ErgestBasha, and even more: SQL-2016, DB2, Mimer, PostgreSQL and Teradata too. You have them all at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.

Comment: @RickvanderHeide You can post the solution mentioned in the chat as an answer so others who might face the same problem can find it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to [Ergest Basha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16461952/ergest-basha) (in comments of question)

I changed the stopwords of my mysql server: I linked a new file to the `ft_stopword_file`. After that, I restarted my server and rebuild the indexes. Now I can query with previously stopwords.